# How to get disk read/write stats information without new dependencies?

Tags: linux, proc, disk

I understand by installing `dstat`, `iostat` I can get the disk activity stats information.

However, now I am hoping to minimize the dependencies as I don't want to force my script users to install additional stuff.

So I'm wondering if there is any way to read the disk stats information from somewhere in `/proc/`?

Answer (score 6):

You can find disk statistics in two places.

- `/sys/block/<dev>/stat`
- `/proc/diskstats`

Whereas `/proc/diskstats` represents the statistics of each single block device including partitions and device mapper devices.
Unfortunately these numbers do not provide *per second* statistics but a grand total of the single statistics. So you would have to write a script that monitors the figures over a given time, then do the math to get a *per second* result. This job is done by `dstat` and `iostat`.
A more comprehensive description of these files can be found in the kernel documentation [Documentation/block/stat.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt) and [Documentation/iostats.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt).

Most users want to install the packages containing `iostat`as the dependencies aren't too huge. `dstat` depends on `pyhton2` but most distros have `python2` installed anyways.